# JS, JQuery and Sharepoint in Script Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Is there anyway to use JQuery script only for HTML script added in Sharepoint Script Editor so it doesn't override main Sharepoint JS scripts implemented in site?

Comment: simply add jquery reference in a script editor webpart. what does it override?

Comment: It overrides JQuery 2 on the main page which conflict Foundations JS...i only need jquery 3 for a special part of the site for an app